# How to save timing in laravel database

Tags: mysql, laravel

**What is the best column type of MySQL to store time limit?**

I need to store timing like: `5:30 (5 minutes and 30 seconds)` then i will use this time to count down for users but I'm not sure what kind of column is the best for such data?

Comment: Use the smallest unit(secs) and save it as an `Int` or `BigInt`. You can easily convert that back to hh:mm:ss after retrieval.

Comment: @UdoE. so you mean i save it as `330 (seconds)` then convert it to `mm:ss` in my view?

Comment: @mafortis Yes, that's exactly what they mean.